# Java: How to convert ip address to binary and hex

Tags: java, binary, hex, converters

I am creating an IP Converter.
You will have to type in the IP-Address with a scanner in a String format.

For Example: String = "192.168.10.1"

How can I convert the String to Binary with the split method?

My converter yet:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Adapt {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int zahl;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Eingabe Zahl: ");
        zahl = scanner.nextInt();
        if (zahl > 0 && zahl <= 255) {
             String hex = Integer.toHexString(zahl);         
             String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(zahl);       
             System.out.println("Hex: " + hex);           
             System.out.println("Bin: " + bin);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Eingabe ungültig, nur Zahlen zwischen 0 - 255 verwenden.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can I get the IP-Address without the dots and convert it to Binary and Hex?

The output would have to look like: 1111.1111.1111.1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input by '.' and convert each part to binary and hexadecimal

```
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder hexa = new StringBuilder();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Eingabe Zahl: ");
    String zahl = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] ipArray = zahl.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i < ipArray.length; i++) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(ipArray[i]);
        if (temp > 0 && temp <= 255) {

            hexa.append(Integer.toHexString(temp));
            hexa.append('.');
            binary.append(Integer.toBinaryString(temp));
            binary.append('.');
        }
    }
    hexa.deleteCharAt(hexa.length() - 1);
    binary.deleteCharAt(binary.length() - 1);

    System.out.println("Hex: " + hexa.toString());
    System.out.println("Bin: " + binary.toString());
```

Comment: This will leave . at the end of `hexa` and `binary` strings.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević Thanks for your findings :-) I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `zahl.Split(".");` and use the `.toBinaryString()` method on the separate pieces.

Answer (score 0):

One of the effective way of getting this done by taking your input as string (which you have already mentioned in the first line of the question) as below:

```
public class adapt {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Eingabe Zahl: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    String hex = "";
    String bin = null;

    if (input != null) {
        input = input.replace(".", "");

        char[] messChar = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < messChar.length; i++) {
            hex += Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]) + " ";
        }
        bin = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(input));

        System.out.println("Hex: " + hex);
        System.out.println("Bin: " + bin);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Eingabe ungültig, nur Zahlen zwischen 0 - 255 verwenden.");
    }
}
```

}